# The json data having date format of ISO 8601 format I want to change the format to dd/mm/yy

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, material-ui, project, react-table

import React, { useState } from "react"; import { MaterialReactTable } from "material-react-table"; import Fuse from "fuse.js"; import { Slider, TextField, IconButton, Drawer } from "@mui/material"; import { DatePicker } from "@mui/x-date-pickers"; import GroupingDropdown from "./GroupingDropDown"; import DateTimeFormatter from "./DateTimeFormatter"; import CategorySubcategoryFilter from "./CategorySubcategoryFilter"; import FilterListIcon from "@mui/icons-material/FilterList"; import SortIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Sort"; import GroupIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Group"; import SortingFilter from "./SortingFilter";  const DataTable = ({ data, columns }) => {   const [columnVisibility, setColumnVisibility] = useState({});   const [globalFilter, setGlobalFilter] = useState("");   const [nameFilter, setNameFilter] = useState("");   const [categoryFilter, setCategoryFilter] = useState([]);   const [subcategoryFilter, setSubcategoryFilter] = useState([]);   const [priceRange, setPriceRange] = useState([0, 1000]);   const [createdAtRange, setCreatedAtRange] = useState([null, null]);   const [grouping, setGrouping] = useState([]);   const [showFilterDrawer, setShowFilterDrawer] = useState(false);   const [showSortingDrawer, setShowSortingDrawer] = useState(false);   const [showGroupingDrawer, setShowGroupingDrawer] = useState(false);   const [sortedData, setSortedData] = useState(data);    const fuse = new Fuse(sortedData, {     keys: ["name"],     includeMatches: true,   });    const handleSorting = (columnKey) => {     const sorted = [...sortedData].sort((a, b) => {       if (a[columnKey] < b[columnKey]) return -1;       if (a[columnKey] > b[columnKey]) return 1;       return 0;     });     setSortedData(sorted);   };    const filteredData = data.filter((item) => {     return (       (fuse         .search(globalFilter)         .map((result) => result.item.name)         .includes(item.name) ||         globalFilter === "") &&       (fuse         .search(nameFilter)         .map((result) => result.item.name)         .includes(item.name) ||         nameFilter === "") &&       (categoryFilter.length === 0 || categoryFilter.includes(item.category)) &&       (subcategoryFilter.length === 0 ||         subcategoryFilter.includes(item.subcategory)) &&       item.price >= priceRange[0] &&       item.price <= priceRange[1] &&       (createdAtRange[0] === null ||         createdAtRange[1] === null ||         (new Date(item.createdAt) >= createdAtRange[0] &&           new Date(item.createdAt) <= createdAtRange[1]))     );   });    const handleGroupingChange = (columnIds) => {     setGrouping(columnIds);     setShowGroupingDrawer(false);   };    return (     <>       <div         style={{           display: "flex",           alignItems: "flex-start",           flexDirection: "row-reverse",           padding: "10px",         }}       >         <input           value={globalFilter || ""}           onChange={(e) => setGlobalFilter(e.target.value)}           placeholder="Search..."           style={{             marginRight: "10px",             padding: "8px",             border: "1px solid #ccc",             borderRadius: "5px",             fontSize: "14px",             outline: "none",           }}         />         <input           value={nameFilter || ""}           onChange={(e) => setNameFilter(e.target.value)}           placeholder="Filter by name..."           style={{             marginRight: "10px",             padding: "8px",             border: "1px solid #ccc",             borderRadius: "5px",             fontSize: "14px",             outline: "none",           }}         />         <IconButton onClick={() => setShowFilterDrawer(true)}>           <FilterListIcon />         </IconButton>         <IconButton onClick={() => setShowSortingDrawer(true)}>           <SortIcon />         </IconButton>         <IconButton onClick={() => setShowGroupingDrawer(true)}>           <GroupIcon />         </IconButton>       </div>        <MaterialReactTable         columns={columns}         data={filteredData}         columnVisibility={columnVisibility}         onColumnVisibilityChange={setColumnVisibility}         enableSorting         globalFilter={globalFilter}         enableGrouping         grouping={grouping}         renderCell={({ cell }) => {           if (             cell.column.accessorKey === "createdAt" ||             cell.column.accessorKey === "updatedAt"           ) {             return <DateTimeFormatter value={cell.value} />;           }           return cell.renderedCellValue;         }}  // DateTimeFormatter.jsx  import React from "react"; import dayjs from "dayjs";  const DateTimeFormatter = ({ value }) => {   console.log("Original value:", value); // Debugging statement   const dateTime = dayjs(value);   console.log("Formatted date:", dateTime.format("DD/MM/YY")); // Debugging statement   const formattedDateTime = dateTime.format("DD/MM/YY");    return <span>{formattedDateTime}</span>; };  export default DateTimeFormatter; //json.data   {         "id": 1,         "name": "Nutrition Attachment",         "category": "Health",         "subcategory": "Nutrition",         "createdAt": "2016-03-24T05:28:03.099+05:30",         "updatedAt": "2016-03-24T05:28:03.099+05:30",         "price": 24.99,         "sale_price": 21.95     },  In my code json data having date format like different I want date format be like dd/mm/yycan anyone help for fix the issue In these stackoverflow shows error while question posting  It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

In my code json data having date format like different I want date format be like dd/mm/yycan anyone help for fix the issue In these stackoverflow shows error while question posting  It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Comment: Please format your code

Answer (score 0):

You have dates in ISO8601 format.

You can create a new Date object from any string in this format and then extract the different parts of the date to compose your preferred format

```js
const date = new Date("2016-03-24T05:28:03.099+05:30");

const day = date.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0');
const month = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0'); // months in JS are indexed from 0
const year = date.getFullYear().toString().slice(-2); // 2 last digits

const formattedDate = `${day}/${month}/${year}`;

console.log(formattedDate ); // Result: "24/03/16"
```

I hope that it will help.